# F# insert a list into SQL Server

Tags: sql, database, list, f#

I'm stuck at the moment trying to figure out a method of inserting into SQL Server from F#.

I have an F# function that iterates through all files inside a folder following a user-defined pattern. Then I can use the returned data to put in a list or (ideally) insert into a database.

I already have a working insert-into-sql function that works properly:

```ml
let execNonQuery conn s =
let comm = 
    new SqlCeCommand(s, conn)
try 
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery() |> ignore
with e ->
    printf "Error : %A\n" e

let string = "insert into MyTable (MyColumn) values ('test .. again')"
execNonQuery conn string; // works
```

I'm trying to get this method to work properly:

```ml
let rec getAllFiles dir pattern =
    seq { yield! Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir, pattern)
          for d in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(dir) do
              yield! getAllFiles d pattern }

let getApplications (dir : string) (extension : string) = 
    getAllFiles  dir extension
    //|> Seq.toList // If I need to create a list of returned values
    |> Seq.iter (fun s -> SQLInsertString s) // This does not work as it complains about the function not being of type unit
```

If I use `Seq.toList` only and call the function as per below, it works:

```ml
getApplications "C:\Admin" "*.txt" // works
```

The other thing I don't understand is how can you create a working insert command that takes in a string for Value. For example:

```ml
let SQLInsertString s = "insert into MyTable (MyColumn) values (%s)" //does not work
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to pass parameters to a query is to use `SqlCeParameter`. This is easier than composing strings (because you don't need to encode strings and escape quotes) and it is also safer, because you avoid [SQL injection attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Here is a basic sample:

```
let sqlInsertString value = 
  // Create and open connection ('use' makes sure it gets closed at the end)
  use conn = new SqlCeConnection("...");
  conn.Open()
  // Create a command with a parameter named '@str'
  let cmd = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO MyTable (MyColumn) values (@str)", conn)
  // Create parameter '@str' with string value 'value' and add it to the command
  let param = new SqlCeParameter("@str", SqlDbType.NVarChar, value)
  cmd.Parameters.Add(param)
  // Now run the command (exception handling omitted)
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() |> ignore
```

Using this function, you should now be able to use `Seq.iter`. The function takes a `string` to be inserted and returns `unit` (no value), so it can be passed to `Seq.iter`:

```
let getApplications (dir : string) (extension : string) =  
  getAllFiles  dir extension 
  |> Seq.iter (fun s -> sqlInsertString s)
```

Alternatively, you can write the last line just as `|> Seq.iter sqlInsertString`. If you do that, you're basically saying that the argument `s` should be directly passed to the `sqlInsertString` function.

Comment: Thank you very much Tomas, works like a charm. Now I undertand it better too

Answer (score 5):

You're almost there. The problem is `sqlInsertString` returns `string` which is not legal to use in `Seq.iter`.

What you're doing with `sqlInsertString` is to create a string using string formats. It fits nicely with `sprintf` function:

```
let sqlInsertString s = 
    sprintf "insert into MyTable (MyColumn) values (%s)" s
```

Now you can use `execNonQuery` on results of `sqlInsertString` to actually insert data into database. Since `execNonQuery` returns `unit`, it could be easily used in `Seq.iter`:

```
// Assuming conn is a global and already defined variable.
let getApplications (dir : string) (extension : string) = 
    getAllFiles  dir extension
    |> Seq.iter (fun s -> execNonQuery conn (sqlInsertString s))
```

Since type annotation is redundant, your code could be rewritten in a more idiomatic way:

```
let getApplications dir extension conn = 
    getAllFiles dir extension
    |> Seq.iter (sqlInsertString >> execNonQuery conn)
```

Comment: Many thanks for this. This answer also works like a charm. I had to choose one answer to be the answer as expected and Tomas's explained how to use paramaters.